why can't a specialized constructor function of a template class with default template param have arguments?
here's a template class with default template parameter:
#include <cstdio>
constexpr int d = 1;

template <int a = d> struct test;

template <> struct test<1> {
  test(int a) { printf("%d\n", a); }
};
template <> struct test<2> {
  test() { printf("%d\n", 2); }
};
int main() { test t{1}; }

oddly enough, if d=1 it won't compile, while d=2 it's fine. if I want use it when d=1, I have to do it like this: test<> t{1};. isn't it kind of counter-intuitive?

update

sorry for the misunderstanding, if d=2, you have to compile it like this:
int main() {test t;} /// since test<2> has no argument for constructor

gcc version: 11.2
no special compile commands

update 2

maybe this code would be better to understand:

#define D 1

template <int a = D> struct test;

template <> struct test<1> {
  test(int a) {}
};
template <> struct test<2> {
  test() {}
};

#if D == 1
void func() {
  // won't compile here
  // test t{1};
  test<> t1{1};
}
#elif D == 2
void func() {
  test<> t{};
  test t2{};
}
#endif

int main() { func(); }

error message:
qmp.cpp: In function ‘void func()’:
qmp.cpp:17:11: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   17 |   test t{1};
      |           ^
qmp.cpp:17:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘test(int)’
qmp.cpp:5:29: note: candidate: ‘template<int a> test()-> test<a>’
    5 | template <int a = D> struct test;
      |                             ^~~~
qmp.cpp:5:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
qmp.cpp:17:11: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
   17 |   test t{1};
      |           ^
qmp.cpp:5:29: note: candidate: ‘template<int a> test(test<a>)-> test<a>’
    5 | template <int a = D> struct test;
      |                             ^~~~
qmp.cpp:5:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
qmp.cpp:17:11: note:   mismatched types ‘test<a>’ and ‘int’
   17 |   test t{1};


please include the errror message in the question

This doesn't compile for neither value of d for me because template argument deduction fails: https://godbolt.org/z/3hGe1nd7Y

Please also include which compiler(s) you tried with which C++ standard (-std=c++xx).

test<1>(int a) is not valid in c++20. See Is having a declaration Stack(); for the default ctor valid inside a class template

This doesn't have anything to do with default args it seems.

@user12002570 actually, test<1>(int a) is not the point, I replaced it with test(int), there's not too much difference

test<> t{1}; uses the default and all is fine. test t{1}; attempts class tempalte argument deduction and fails. Yor interpretation that a constructor with .... cannot have arguments is misguided. The issue is merely that the automatic deduction guides fail for ctad.

test t{1}; cannot have  a deduced, because default value is not depedant, specialization cannot be chosen as it goes on deduction route, and primary template is incomplete. Correct syntax in that case is test<> t{1};

@陈泽霖 Basically, only primary templates are looked up first. Specializations are only looked up afterwards.

class template with default argument requires Empty Angle Brackets <> and Omit angle brackets when template has default parameters

rather than adding more variants of the code and further fragmenting the question you better post 1 complete example together with the resulting error message. If you then have another example, either your doubts about that other example get cleared by answering the question about the first or you can open a new question. Frankly, I dont see the point of the latest edit at all. "code is more clear" what do you mean by that? Is this code producing another error? why do you not tell us the error? Or does it compile? In that case, whats the relevance?

note that you also do not have to keep different variants of the question and you need not add "update" or similar. If someone wants to see the edit history they can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78383073/revisions. The question does not need to reflect its own edit history, but rather should be clear and focused.

Your setup doesn't offer any source for template argument deduction. Attempting a default value for template argument happens only if you provide template argument list, which you didn't.
If you don't like empty chevrons , e.g. for general use within other templates, there is a workaround for this, using an alias:
constexpr int d = 1;

template <int a> struct test_impl;

template <> struct test_impl<1> {
  test_impl(int a) { printf("%d\n", a); }
};
template <> struct test_impl<2> {
  test_impl() { printf("%d\n", 2); }
};

using test = test_impl<d>;

int main() { test t{1}; }

C++20 custom deduction guide solution:
constexpr int d = 1;

template <int a> struct test;
template <int a = d> test(int) -> test<d>;  // C++20

template <> struct test<1> {
  test(int a) { printf("%d\n", a); }
};
template <> struct test<2> {
  test() { printf("%d\n", 2); }
};

int main() { test t{1}; }


thx, I actually knew typedef would work, as std::string works like that. I just don't know why it won't work without using alias.

@陈泽霖 unlike typedef, using-statement can be a template too, which expands athe range of possibilities.

@陈泽霖 the answer explains why it does not work. Do you know what ctad is? If not you need to read about it, because your question boils down to how ctad works https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

@463035818_is_not_an_ai thx, didn't know much about it, I'll read it

@陈泽霖 perhaps it will help you to try to compile your code with c++14 or earlier and understand the error there. Spoiler: the reason test t{1}; does not compile pre c++17 is that class template arguments are not deduced from arguments to the constructor. If you understood that you are ready to dive into ctad :)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai techncally it should have been obvious before C++14 too, especially  looking at case where a constructor can be a template too.. iit all boils down when substitution ends and instantiation begins. Tbh, cppreference is kind of confusing there.. they fused large number of separate rules into one big blurb of information. I can't make head from tail there

@Swift-FridayPie I suppose in hindsight many things about templates could have been simpler. I agree that this isnt cppref at its best, though its still the only source (apart from the standard) I have no worries to recommend as an entry point for futher reading and research
